# Adding column based on dynamic criteria that changes for every row in snowflake

Tags: sql, select, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window

Trying to add a column that counts distinct customers in snowflake based on criteria that changes for every row i.e. needs to count customers between 52 weeks before current week_ending date to current week_ending date.

The query that goes like

```
select week_ending, sales, last_year_cust_count
from table where year = 2022
```

now i want the last_year_cust_count to have distinct customers between 52 weeks before week_ending till current week_ending and this needs to show following results as example

| Week_ending | Sales | last_year_cust_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/01/22 | $300 | 3479 |
| 09/01/22 | $350 | 3400 |
| 16/01/22 | $450 | 3500 |

... and so on

Answer (score 0):

The optimal way to solve this over complex structure, is to use a bitmap, and then roll that up to the projections you over.

You should read [Using Bitmaps to Compute Distinct Values for Hierarchical Aggregations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-bitmaps-for-distinct-counts.html)

The simple, non-performant way is to self join and throw processing power at it.

```
select a.week_ending, a.sales, count(distinct b.customer) as last_year_cust_count
from table_a as a
join table_a as b
    on <filter that I cannot bothered writing to select last 52 weeks base on years and weeks>
where year = 2022
```